# iFrame and changing page when submitted

Tags: html, css, vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js

I have an iFrame element on my website that provides a form that gets submitted after some questions are answered. I am trying to then have the page redirect to a thank you page when it completes but have been having difficulty doing this.
Is there a way to detect when the form has been successfully submitted at all? I've tried with onsubmit and onload calls but these don't seem to help. I can provide code if necessary but currently on mobile.

I am using vue.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what I think you are asking.  This is a JavaScript solution that you can open multiple pages in one iframe.  **I'm also on mobile so I can't test this and I am doing it from memory but I hope this atleast gets you started.

Html:

```
<button onclick="nextPage(frameSource)">Submit</button>
<iframe class="myFrame" src="" id="myIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
function nextPage(frameSource){
     document.getElementById("mainIframe").src = frameSource;

}

function choosePages(){
     var thePages = pageName + ".html";
     nextPage(thePages);
}
```

Comment: Will this redirect me to another page or allow me to show a box with thank you text for submitting the iFrame form?

Comment: Redirect you to another page once the button is clicked. Just add the main page to the iframe source then add the thank you page as the frameSource. The frameSource page should appear on button click.